# 2 Navbar-Brands on One Navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a section of `_Layout` page:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>
          <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand brand">My Company Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ZpKFLgy6O3) to demonstrate the issue.

I would like to add my company's name to the Navbar with the same style as my App Name which is using the class `navbar-brand`.

Now to get my Company's name to the center I added the class `brand`.

But now the issue is when I hover over the *App Name* or any part of the navbar (except for the `About`, `Contact`, and `Home` links) then *My Company Name* is the active link.

How do I make both My Company's Name and the App Name both active links with the style they currently have Active Links?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It's because the size is 100%, you're always over it, so it's highlighted...*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/l116cll2on

**CSS**:

```
.brand {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

}
.brand-inner{
  left: -50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
          <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">App Name</a>
          <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" class="navbar-brand brand">
            <div class="brand-inner"> My Company Name</div>
          </a>
```